# jquery tablesorter scroller: how set focus to scroll by keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, tablesorter, scroller

Sorry for my English.

I am using tablesorter 2.0 and scroller.

I call on my page. When I push the table then it works scroll by keys. But I want to without pressing on the table. Practically by load the page.

set `$("#tableStockSLI").focus()` does not work.
How can I do this?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.widgets-filter-formatter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascripts/widget-scroller.js"></script>
```

```js
            $("#tableStockSLI").tablesorter({
                theme: 'blue',
                widthFixed : true,
                showProcessing: true,                     
               widgets: [ "zebra","filter", "scroller"],
                widgetOptions : {
                 scroller_height : 300,
                 scroller_upAfterSort: false,
                    scroller_jumpToHeader: false
                },


               sortList: [[1,0],[2,0]]

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give the scroller div focus, you just need to give the scroller container (`tablesorter-scroller-table`) a `tabindex`. Try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4302/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widthFixed: true,
        showProcessing: true,
        widgets: ["zebra", "filter", "scroller"],
        widgetOptions: {
            scroller_height: 200,
            scroller_upAfterSort: false,
            scroller_jumpToHeader: false
        },
        sortList: [[1, 0],[2, 0]],
        initialized: function(){
            // give scroller a tabindex to allow focusing
            $('.tablesorter-scroller-table').attr('tabindex', 1);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function(){
        // keyboard pageup/down now always works in scroll window
        $('.tablesorter-scroller-table').focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I do this with 2 Tables? I can't selected by Id from table! Has the Scrollertable a id?

Comment: I have solved for 2 tables. I use 2 divs and search inside after '.tablesorter-scroller-table' . $("#divTable1").find('.tablesorter-scroller-table').each(function (index, obj){$(this).attr('tabindex', 1);}); set tabindex. And with $("#divTable1").find('.tablesorter-scroller-table').each(function (index, obj){$(this).focus();}); set focus. Thanks